# iOS JavaScriptCore.framework Validation

Tags: ios, xcode, javascriptcore

I have an iOS app that I'm trying to submit to the App Store but it fails validation because I have JavaScriptCore.Framework library linked in my project - hence cannot submit my app to the App Store. Here's the error message that I'm receiving when validating my app:

`The app links to non-public libraries in Payload/MyAppName.app/MyAppName: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore`

Is it possible in any way to link this library without getting validation errors?

Comment: It is a public framework since iOS7. For previous iOS versions you have to work with the open source JSC code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known bug of the automated validation for AppStore submissions. If the deployment target is set to iOS 7 and later, then you do not get any problems, if the deployment target is iOS 5 (and probably 6 as well?), then you get this false failure message. The JavaScripCore frameworks seems to be the only one that is affected by this bug.

Even though Apple knows about this bug, please send a bug report to Apple. The number of bug reports Apple gets, tells them how relevant a problem is. So only if enough developers report this bug, there's a chance to get it prioritized and fixed sooner.

Throwing away support for iOS 5/6 (no longer supporting iPad 1 and iPod touch 4g) should allow you to submit the App without problems, but this is not an option for all Apps.